# PHP Custom Sort Routines (uksort?)

Tags: php, arrays, sorting, ksort

Utilising the power of `uksort` (although happy to be directed elsewhere if necessary), I'm looking at implementing a custom sort routine to sort, in ascending order, an array based on its key.

The problem I'm having is the key is a string, but I'd like to treat the key as an int (in two parts). My array is as follows:

```
[20-2 => object, 20-1 => object, 4-1 => object, 3-1 => object]
```

What I would like to do is order primarily by the int value of the first half of the key, then the second half (where there are multiple entries that share the first half). For instance, I would like to order to the following:

```
[3-1 => object, 4-1 => object, 20-1 => object, 20-2 => object]
```

Thanks

Tried `ksort`, but because my keys are strings it pretty much did nothing

**Edit:** I do NOT have access to the creation of the array in order to change the keys into something more easily sortable. I am using PHP7

Comment: Please share more details, like the source array in PHP code, the target array, and your attempts to resolve the problem

Comment: `uksort` should work just fine with a correct implementation. See https://3v4l.org/T0C5U

Comment: @nice_dev That looks suspiciously like an answer. Any reason not to post it as one?

Comment: @nice_dev Your solution works perfectly. I think my issue here is that I need to go away and get a better understanding of how to implement a custom sort correctly, in all situations, rather than relying on PHP to do the heavy lifting

Comment: @IMSoP I am under the impression that there would surely be a dupe for this. Hence, not taking any risks since mods would later on close this page with a dupe post.

Comment: @JoeHogan Makes sense. PHP can do the heavy lifting for you, but it's better to make and store the data in the right format to avoid redundant  manipulations in the future.

Comment: @nice_dev Answering in a comment is the worst of both worlds, from the site's point of view: it can't be upvoted or accepted as an Answer (nor edited or downvoted, if necessary); but the person asking the question gets what they need, so doesn't need to engage with the site any more, and we're left with a stub.

Comment: As for duplicates, we have a general reference on sorting in PHP, so if it's just a case of needing to understand the principles, rather than fixing a problem with an existing implementation, that would be the place to go.

Comment: Thanks all for your help and clarification of site best practices

Comment: @IMSoP Makes sense to me now. I will abide by it.